# "Keep Something In The Know" meaning

Tags: idioms

I am reading "**Head First Design Patterns**" book, chapter 2 ,entitled "**Keeping your Objects in the know**" but the title doesn't make sense to me.

what "Keep Something In The Know" means in this case and also in generally speaking?

Comment: Is this book about using programming languages, and referring to the Objects in a coding sense?

Comment: @katatahito Yes it is. Head First Design pattern, Chapter 2

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the book title in. I suspect that the first paragraph of that chapter would also give us helpful context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "keep something/someone in the know" means to have information which is not accessible by everyone. So if you are reading a book about programming, then keeping your objects in the know would mean, that you probably should keep their information secret from the outside, but known to each other.

[Source.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-know)

Comment: You should add a reference source to improve this answer

Comment: Your source does not support this interpretation. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Keeping **someone** in the know" is making sure that they have information which is not generally known. (That is what Collins dictionary, the source in Tymek's answer, says).

"Keeping **something** in the know" is completely meaningless to me, a native speaker. I believe it is either a mistake, or written by a non-native writer whose grasp of English idiom is not as good as they think it is.